# Корректно ли обрабатывать ошибку в конструкторе?

Tags: c#

Можно ли обрабатывать ошибки подобным образом в конструкторе или нужно писать отдельный метод? (таблиц в бд будет гораздо больше и подобных вызовов как для Users соответственно тоже)

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserDatabase> Users { get; set; } = null!;

        public ApplicationContext()
        {
            if (Database.EnsureCreated() == false)
                throw new EmptyDatabaseExeption("database is empty");
            if (Users.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = 1").FirstOrDefault() == null)
            throw new EmptyDatabaseExeption("table is empty");
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Выкидывание исключений делегирует обработку ошибок вызывающему коду.

Comment: Смотря какую ошибку. Смотря что с ней делать.. Смотря в каком классе. | DbContext должен быть максимально легковесным и создаваться быстро. Поэтому показанным проверкам не место в его конструкторе.